# mapstruct: mapping from two different fields

Tags: mapstruct

How to make mapping from two different fields? I need to set b.url to a.x.y.z.url if it exists otherwise to a.k.l.m.url:

b.url = exists(a.x.y.z.url) ? a.x.y.z.url : exists(a.k.l.m.url) ? a.k.l.m.url : defaultValue

Expression might help but it will be quite long expression if I check all nested fields for null, like "a != null && a.getX() != null && a.getX().getY() != null && a.getX().getY().getZ() != null && a.getX().getY().getZ().getURL() != null ? a.getX().getY().getZ().getURL() : ..."

Thanks,
Pavel

Answer (score 0):

You can use MapStruct [`@AfterMapping`](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#customizing-mappings-with-before-and-after) to gain access to the mapping object.

```
@AfterMapping
protected void mapUrl(B b, @MappingTarget A a) {
    //You will do your logic here
}
```

Theoretically you could do it via an expression by declaring you Mapper as an abstract class and defining a `getUrl(A a)` method. They in your expression you could call `getUrl(a)`.

I would suggest to use the `@AfterMapping`, as it is cleaner (in my opinion)